# How to schedule a job by node-schedule module at any time of specific timezone

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, npm, timezone

I want to schedule a job at 15:00 Copenhagen Time irrespective of where my server is running. I am using 'node-schedule' npm module.

Comment: Convert "Copenhagen Time" to UTC, then set the Date using `new Date(Date.UTC(...))`. How will you deal with daylight saving?

Answer (score 9):

`node-schedule` has `RecurrenceRule()` which you could use to specify timezone for the rule.

```
let schedule = require('node-schedule');
let rule = new schedule.RecurrenceRule();

// your timezone
rule.tz = 'Europe/Copenhagen';

// runs at 15:00:00
rule.second = 0;
rule.minute = 0;
rule.hour = 15;

// schedule
schedule.scheduleJob(rule, function () {
  console.log('Hello World!');
});
```

Timezones listed here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones

Comment: Are those timezones take into account summer time ?

Answer (score 1):

What you did is ok, but you should set the time with a lib like http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/.

`var a = moment.tz("2013-11-18 11:55", "America/Toronto");`

Comment: How it can solve my purpose to set job timing on the basis of specific timezone?

Comment: As per what @RobG said. Convert Copenhagen Time to UTC and then schedule the job.

Answer (score 0):

I worked around so much for this problem and found a solution.

**Copenhagen/Time zone: Central European Time Zone(UTC+01:00)**
UTC offset for CET(Central European Time) timezone is +1:00.

So to convert copenhagen time to UTC time, we need to subtract one hour from copenhagen time.
Example: Copenhagen 15:00 = 14:00 UTC

If we want to schedule a job at 15:00 copenhagen and server is running anywhere then we can use following approach:

```
var copenhagenHour = 15;//You can set any hour at which you want to schedule a job
var copenHagenMinutes = 0;//You can set any minute
var date = new Date();
date.setUTCHours(copenhagenHour - 1);//-1 defines the UTC time offset for a particular timezone
date.setUTCMinutes(copenHagenMinutes);

var scheduledRoutes = schedule.scheduleJob({hour: date.getHours(), minute: date.getMinutes()}, function(){
console.log('call scheduled job');
});
```

The above console 'call scheduled job' will be printed at 15:00 in copenhagen and at 19:30 in India.

It worked for me.

**Note:** Currently I didn't consider 'Daylight Saving Time'.

Comment: You're assuming that the local date will be the same as Copenhagen date. It may not be, so you may be setting the hours on the wrong day. You're also assuming the timezone is an even multiple of 1 hr different, when some have 15 minute and 30 minute offsets.